# Extjs grid relies on external store, not rendering properly

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs6

I have an Extjs (version 6, classic API) panel with a grid in it. This grid has its own store that is ready to go within initComponent(). It's iterating over those records just fine. The issue is that one column has a custom renderer that relies on another store. This store may or may not be loaded depending on a few different factors. As a result, the grid doesn't render that column correctly. I find myself in a bit of a pickle as to how to deal with that. The basic concept is that the value for that column is just a key that means nothing to the user. This key is looked up in the non-grid store to display the data correctly using the renderer attribute in the grid column. All of the code is executing fine, but it's the issue of having that store loaded, and when it does load, it does not trigger a rerender of that column as it's not the store for the grid itself.

I could load the store synchronously before initComponent() is complete, but that's hardly ideal. I can't tell it to wait for the store to load during the render phase as that will leave the column blank if the store isn't loaded. I need to trigger a rerender of that column somehow or get it to properly wait if the non-grid store isn't loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to tell a grid to rerender a certain column. So you will have to refresh the whole grid:

```
myGrid.on('afterrender',function(grid) {
    externalStore.on('load',function() {
        grid.getView().refresh();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I had to do. It's a simple grid, so the rerender isn't time-consuming and appears nearly instantaneous to the user.